# Counter showing double data when fetch it from fread function

Tags: php

I create a counter function in PHP means if someone access or visit a web page so it will show count in file.txt(it contain the number of counts) and on the web page also. but now I want to fetch counts form file.txt and show it on another page. I tried PHP fread operation but it showing counting in double. suppose if the real number of count is 10 then after fetch it from fread it showing 1010.

I used this code to fetch count from file.txt for showing it to another page.

```
<?php 
$file = fopen("counter.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file !");
echo fgets($file);
//fread($file,filesize("counter.txt"));
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: There's nothing here that will show it twice.

Comment: BTW, you can combine `fopen`, `fread()`, and `fclose` with `file_get_contents("counter.txt")`

Comment: The problem must be with how you're loading this script in the other page.

Comment: Here is my code:     and I want to show the  counter.txt data on other page  <?php
    $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "r");
    if(!$handle)
    {
        echo "could not open the file";
    }
    else 
    {
        $counter=(int )fread($handle,20);fclose($handle);
        $counter++;
        echo"Visitors: ". $counter . "" ;
        $handle= fopen("counter.txt", "w" ) ;
        fwrite($handle,$counter) ;fclose ($handle) ;
    }

Comment: Put the code in the question, it's hard to read in comments.

Comment: BTW, I ask this whenever I see it: why do you write `. ""` at the end of the `echo` line? No one has ever given me an explanation why they do it.

Comment: `<?php
$handle = fopen("counter.txt", "r");
if (!$handle) {
  echo "could not open the file";
} else {
  $counter = (int)fread($handle,20);
  fclose($handle);
  $counter++;
  echo "Visitors: $counter";
  $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "w");
  fwrite($handle, $counter);
  fclose ($handle);
}
?>` is good but for showing the counter into another page you have to save your code as `counter.php` and then invoke it where you want using `<?php include("counter.php"); ?>`

Comment: or if you want only get your counter into another page without to increment it `<?php $counter = file_get_contents("counter.txt"); echo ($counter == 1) ? "Visitor: $counter" : "Visitors: $counter"; ?>`

Comment: If you open the file, what is its contents? Please edit the question to have that too.

Comment: [UpVote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq7YZ.png) [Mark Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB3cT.png) as you can see you can vote and mark answer according to the pictures.. don't forget to vote!

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Counter TEXT are very basics. For writing to `counter.txt` file your code seems Ok:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("counter.txt", "r");
if (!$handle) {
  echo "could not open the file";
} else {
  $counter = (int)fread($handle,20);
  fclose($handle);
  $counter++;
  $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "w");
  fwrite($handle, $counter);
  fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

You can save as `write_counts.php` and invoke into your php files at begin using:

```
<?php include("write_counts.php"); ?>
```

for reading your `counter.txt` instead you can use:

```
<?php $counter = file_get_contents("counter.txt"); echo ($counter == 1) ? "Visitor: $counter" : "Visitors: $counter"; ?>
```

and you can save as `read_counts.php` and invoke into your php files where you like... using:

```
<?php include("read_counts.php"); ?>
```

I hope this helps.